# What is the grammar term that means using pronouns to reduce repetition of nouns?

Tags: grammar, word-request

For instance:

Normally we say "Winston is a victim of the totalitarian regime and I sympathize with **him**" instead of "Winston is a victim of the totalitarian regime and I sympathize with **Winston**".

After an aha moment the word swam into my mind. What I meant is anaphora, then I realized that I asked the wrong question. (Maybe there exists another term in psychology which can explain this phenomenon of false memory retrieval)

The anaphora means "deliberate repetition of the first part of the sentence". But what I needed is not anaphora. Then I wonder how I can express using a term the meaning of what I asked.

Comment: I think you mean the totalitarian regime,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, but **anaphora** *is* the right word.

The problem here is that the word has two meanings - one in rhetoric, and the other in linguistics.

In rhetoric, it means several sentences with the same words at the start of each. Think Churchill's "we shall fight on the beaches" speech.

In linguistics, it means any time you use a word whose meaning refers back to an earlier word of phrase - like many uses of relative pronouns.